# The person receiving notifications ("notifyee" does not seem right...)

Tags: single-word-requests

This in relations to a user interface component in a software.

I am looking for a word to describe a person who is to receive email notifications.

This is a user role, like "manager", "admin", "writer", etc.

Comment: You could perhaps use "addressees" or "addressees for notification".

Answer (score 3):

The person who receives something (a notification, a letter, a package, etc.) is the recipient.

Example dictionary definition from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recipient):

> **recipient**
>   noun
>   A person or thing that receives or is awarded something.
>   ‘the recipient of the Nobel Peace Prize’

It could be used alone, but in the context you describe it may sound better to use a phrase like "notification recipient".